# Display data from arraylist to a listview, counting every repeating object and show as one object

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I am a newbie to android and working on an ecommerce app. I have a model class for the Product (specifying product name, price etc).

```
public class Product implements Serializable {

    /**
     * The item Merchant Name.
     */
    private String merchantName = "";

    /**
     * The item desc.
     */
    private String description = "";

    /**
     * The mrp.
     */
    private String mrp;

    /**
     * The discount.
     */
    private String discount;

    /**
     * The image url.
     */
    private int imageUrl;

    private String productName = "";

    private String productId = "";

    public Product(String description, String mrp, String discount,
                   int imageUrl, String productName, String productId, String merchantName) {

        this.description = description;
        this.mrp = mrp;
        this.discount = discount;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        this.productName = productName;
        this.productId = productId;
        this.merchantName=merchantName;
    }

    public void setMerchantName(String merchantName) {
        this.merchantName = merchantName;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public void setMrp(String mrp) {
        this.mrp = mrp;
    }

    public void setDiscount(String discount) {
        this.discount = discount;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(int imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public void setProductId(String productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getMerchantName(){
        return merchantName; }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public String getMrp() {
        return mrp;
    }

    public String getDiscount() {
        return discount;
    }

    public int getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public String getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

}
```

I want to display the products from an arraylist to a listview. But if there is same product (with same productId) in the arraylist twice, I want it to be displayed it on the ListView in just one row and with quantity- 2 (see image please). Can anyone help me with this please?

[image: See second and third item displaying seperately in the list]

Here is the listview adapter class:

```
public class MyOrdersProducts_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Activity activity;
    ArrayList<Product> cartproductsList;
    Product tempValues;

    public MyOrdersProducts_Adapter(Activity activity,ArrayList<Product> cartproductsList){
        this.activity=activity;
        this.cartproductsList=cartproductsList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return cartproductsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return cartproductsList.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    class MyViewHolder{
        CheckBox checkBox;
        ImageView imageView;
        LinearLayout listRow;
        TextView price,title,quantity;

        public MyViewHolder(View v){
            checkBox=v.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_product);
            imageView=v.findViewById(R.id.img_product_list);
            price=v.findViewById(R.id.price_productlist);
            title=v.findViewById(R.id.title_productlist);
            quantity=v.findViewById(R.id.quantity_productlist);
            listRow=v.findViewById(R.id.productlist_row);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        View rowView=view;
        MyViewHolder holder;

        if(rowView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater=activity.getLayoutInflater();
            rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.myordersproducts_row,null);
            holder=new MyViewHolder(rowView);
            rowView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder= (MyViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        tempValues=cartproductsList.get(i);

        holder.imageView.setImageResource(tempValues.getImageUrl());
        holder.title.setText(tempValues.getProductName());
        holder.price.setText(tempValues.getMrp());

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Please notice I cannot use a HashSet (for creating unique list) or HashMap (to map a Product with Integer count value) because I cannot set data to BaseAdapter from HashSets.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448129/make-a-unique-list-of-objects-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a unique list of objects Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448129/make-a-unique-list-of-objects-java)

Comment: try to check the duplicate products before setting it to the adapter, that would be easy rather than to calculate it in recycler/list view

Comment: Thanks @UMESH0492 Kindly see the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But if there is same product (with same productId) in the arraylist
>   twice

Why not avoid adding products in the `ArrayList` with the same `product id`? Just before you add any product in the `ArrayList`, check if any existing product in the `ArrayList` has a same `product id` or not. If there exists a product with the same `product id`, don't add the product. That way you will have a `ArrayList` of products with unique `product id's`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this will create a unique list. I also need to display the quantity (no. of times a product is repeating). Please note I cannot add quantity variable in the Product model class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a check when adding items to the ArrayList that looks to see if the same product exists already.  Make sure to add a quantity field to the product class, and when you come across a duplicate, just increment the quantity.

Comment: Adding a quantity variable in Product model class is not a good idea in my project. Could you suggest an alternative solution please?

Answer (score 1):

Filter the data before adding it to the `RecyclerView`, for example like this:

```
// Beware, this is pseudo code
void addData(List<Product> items) {
    HashMap<String, ProductItem> newItems = new HashMap<>();
    for (ProductItem item: items) {
        if (newItems.containsKey(item.id)) {
            newItems.get(item.id).incrementQuantity();
        } else {
            newItems.put(item.id, item);
        }
     }
     adapter.add(newItems.values())
}
```